# Can anyone help me with the following code of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I am using this following code which works with three multiple dropdown list, when I select the options from the dropdown menu it makes the `URL` and go to the particular `url` and `loads` the geojson file, and that thing is kind of working fine and the following code is also working fine, but the problem comes when there is a large amount of data in geojson file, in my code it takes the geojson data and send it to the `mapdata(layer1, layer2)` but, its taking a lot of time to load the data, and `mapdata` becomes blank and i don't get the data,
unless i open the debug mode and put the debugger on the mapdata and wait for 10 to 15 seconds until it loads the data, then it works fine,

so I am not sure either the sequence of my code is wrong, or I am running it `onload` function thats issue?

here is my code

```
map.on('load', function() {

        //using the change function to make the URL and fetch the data from the given path   
    document.getElementById('Zone').onchange= function() {
         var zoneVal = this.value
         document.getElementById('year').onchange = function() {
            var yearVal = this.value;
            document.getElementById('month').onchange = function() {
                var monthVal = this.value;
                pathRawGeometery = "http://localhost/thesisViz/mapbox/" + zoneVal + "/" +yearVal+ "/" + monthVal + "/" +zoneVal+"_"+yearVal+"_"+monthVal+"_rawGeometery.geojson";
                pathCleanGeometery = "http://localhost/thesisViz/mapbox/" + zoneVal + "/" +yearVal+ "/" + monthVal + "/" +zoneVal+"_"+yearVal+"_"+monthVal+"_cleanedGeometery.geojson";
                console.log(pathRawGeometery)
                console.log(pathCleanGeometery)

                //reading the Geojson files into an object and sending it to mapData
                $.getJSON(pathRawGeometery, function (data){
                    // progressbarData()
                    myJsonData = data;
                })

                $.getJSON(pathCleanGeometery, function (data){
                    // progressbarData()
                    myJsonDataLayer = data;
                })
                mapData (myJsonData, myJsonDataLayer)
                // layercontrol();
            }
        }
    }       
    });
```

Comment: Use `Promise.all` on the two promises

Comment: @CertainPerformance didn't get your answer?

Comment: See the linked canonical, and look up `Promise.all`

Comment: @CertainPerformance async call helped me.